# Move image from UIScrollView to UIView - Swift 4 PanGesture

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, swift4, uipangesturerecognizer

I want to be able to move an instance of `UIImageView` from a `UIScrollView` to a `UIView` that is outside the containing `UIScrollView`.

I've got the `panGesture` working but a `UIImageView` shows only inside the containing `UIScrollView` when being dragged and gets hidden if going outside the containing `UIScrollView` as shown in the screenshot image.

I've tried something like `someScrollView.sendSubview(toBack: self.view)` to set the layer order and also `imageView.layer.zIndex = ..` but it doesn't seem to work in my case.

How do I achieve something as shown in the screenshot image so it can be dragged to a target `UIView` outside its containing view?
And also if possible, how can I create a new instance of UIImageView as the panGesture begins so the original images stay.

[image]

```
@IBOutlet weak var someScrollView: UIScrollView!
var letters: [String] = ["g","n","d"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    someScrollView.addSubview(createLetters(letters))
    someScrollView.sendSubview(toBack: self.view)
}

func createLetters(_ named: String]) -> [UIImageView] {
    return named.map { name in
        let letterImage = UIImageView()
        letterImage.image = UIImage(named: "\(name)")
        addPanGesture(image: letterImage)
        return letterImage
    }
}

func addPanGesture(image: UIImageView) {
    let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.handlePan(sender:)))
    image.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
}

@objc func handlePan(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = sender.translation(in: view)
    if let imageView = sender.view {
        imageView.center = CGPoint(x:imageView.center.x + translation.x,
                              y:imageView.center.y + translation.y)
    }
    sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)

    switch sender.state {
    case .began:
    ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, it's good practice to prioritize gesture recognizers - tell the scroll view's pan gesture that it won't receive touches on account of your pan gestures (Yours comes first).

```
someScrollView.panGestureRecognizer.require(toFail: yourGestureRecognizer)
```

Unclip scroll-view's subviews to it's bounds - It's subviews will be visible when dragged outside the scrollView's bounds.

```
scrollView.clipsToBounds = false
```

You can convert the frame of your dragged view to the scrollView and newParentView ancestor's coord' system, like this (assuming self.view is scrollView & newParentView's ancestor).

```
let pannedViewFrame = someScrollView.convert(pannedView, to: self.view)
```

Then, in your gesture recognizer's selector, you can test frame intersection of pannedViewFrame and newParentView.frame, like this:

```
// You have an frame intersection 
if pannedViewFrame.intersects(newParentView.frame) {

}
```

Now, if you test intersection of frames when your gesture recognizer's state is `.cancelled`, `.ended` or `.failed`, then:

*The panning has ended* **AND** *pannedView is within newParentView's bounds*

Last step, just convert `pannedViewFrame` to `newParentView.frame`'s coord' using the same trick and added `pannedView` as subview to `newParentView`.

Another solution is to remove the `pannedView` from `scrollView` when GR state is `.began` and add it to `scrollView` and `newParentView`'s common ancestor. The rest is the same as i previously mentioned.